# Diode I-V characteristics

Tags: diodes, cmos, device-characteristics

I am studying device design, starting from diodes. I am using the VisualTCAD simulator which allows us to simulate device fabrication and simulation.

The diode specifications are as follows:

- n-doping: 10^16/cc
- p-doping: 10^19/cc
- p-width: 10n
- p-diffusion length : 10n

[image]

When I simulate this device to plot its I-V characteristics, I get the ones as shown in figure below. Here the forward current seems to saturate after increasing for some voltage range. I was expecting it to increase exponentially after barrier potential. Moreover I also plotted reverse bias characteristics, but was unable to get reverse breakdown. Can someone please highlight what is wrong here?

[image]

I also have another question here. When I try keeping the concentration of n and p regions exactly same, the depletion region is not visible after meshing. What could be the reason for it?

Comment: It looks not like saturation but simply the ohmic limit. Your diode looks extremely small in area, so it is realistic that you get appreciable resistance.

Comment: Is it any close to practical device characteristics?

Comment: @Sparsh practical in what context? There's certainly use cases (on ICs) for microampere diodes. You can basically *always* make up a use case for something. Maybe I need a diode with a high resistive component for my errrr self-compensating least-power amplifier gizmo thingy IC.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly is this ohmic limit

Comment: This might also be velocity saturation.